# How to recursively copy all files with a certain extension in a directory using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-management

I'm trying to write a Python function that copies all .bmp files from a directory and its sub-directories into a specified destination directory.

I've tried using os.walk but it only reaches into the first sub-directory and then stops. Here's what I have so far:

```
def copy(src, dest):

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
        for file in files:
            if file[-4:].lower() == '.bmp':
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(dest, file))
```

What do I need to change so it copies every .bmp file from every sub-directory?

EDIT: This code actually does work, there were just fewer bitmap files in the source directory than anticipated. However, for the program I am writing, I prefer the method using glob shown below.

Comment: Your code copy all bmp files that are in src in the dest folder without coping the file hierarchy : 
`src/1.bmp
src/dir1/2.bmp
src/dir2/3.bmp `
in 
`dest/1.bmp
dest/2.bmp
dest/3.bmp`
Is that what you wanted ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `glob` with `recursive=True`, which, with the `**` specifier, will recursively traverse directories and find all files satisfying a format specifier:

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

def copy(src, dest):
    for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(src, '**', '*.bmp'), recursive=True):
        new_path = os.path.join(dest, os.path.basename(file_path))
        shutil.copy(file_path, new_path)
```